# How can I rotate and scale an ARKit model using gestures?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to rotate and scale an ARKit model like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1SA3AZumeU&feature=youtu.be):

Here is my code:

Add Gestures:

```
let tapGesure = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesure)

let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(moveNode(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

let rotateGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotateNode(_:)))
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rotateGesture)
```

Here are the corresponding methods:

Tap Gesture:

```
// MARK: - Gesture Recognizers
@objc func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = gesture.location(in: sceneView)
    guard let hitTestResult = sceneView.hitTest(location, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }
    let position = SCNVector3Make(hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.x,
                                  hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.y,
                                  hitTestResult.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
    addFoodModelTo(position: position)
}
```

Pan Gesture with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`:

```
@objc func moveNode(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if !isRotating {

        //1. Get The Current Touch Point
        let currentTouchPoint = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)

        //2. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
        guard let hitTest = self.sceneView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }

        //3. Convert To World Coordinates
        let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform

        //4. Set The New Position
        let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)

        //5. Apply To The Node
        baseNode.simdPosition = float3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)  
    }
}
```

Rotate Gesture with `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`:

```
@objc func rotateNode(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer){

    //1. Get The Current Rotation From The Gesture
    let rotation = Float(gesture.rotation)

        //2. If The Gesture State Has Changed Set The Nodes EulerAngles.y
        if gesture.state == .changed{
            isRotating = true
            baseNode.eulerAngles.y = currentAngleY + rotation
        }

        //3. If The Gesture Has Ended Store The Last Angle Of The Cube
        if(gesture.state == .ended) {
            currentAngleY = baseNode.eulerAngles.y
            isRotating = false
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rotation gesture implement the following methodology:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
                                                      action: #selector(rotation))

    self.sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
}
```

then:

```
let myScene = SCNScene(named: "scene.scn")!
let modelNode: SCNNode = myScene.rootNode
var originalRotation: SCNVector3? = nil
```

also you can check any important condition:

```
private func nodeMethod(at position: CGPoint) -> SCNNode? {

    let n = self.sceneView.hitTest(position, options: nil).first(where: { 
        $0.node !== modelNode 
    })?.node

    return n
}
```

and then:

```
@objc func rotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

    let location = gesture.location(in: self.sceneView)
    
    guard let node = nodeMethod(at: location) else { return }
    
    switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            originalRotation = node.eulerAngles
        case .changed:
            guard var originalRotation = originalRotation else { return }
            originalRotation.y -= Float(gesture.rotation)
            node.eulerAngles = originalRotation
        default:
            originalRotation = nil
    }
}
```

P.S.

Check where is a pivot point of your model located. If it's outside model's container, your model will be rotated and scaled unpredictably. Control pivot point's position using the following code:

```
modelNode.simdPivot.columns.3.z = 0.25
```

Also read about `Quaternion` vs `Euler` Rotation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997832/scnnode-z-rotation-axis-stays-constant-while-x-and-y-axes-change-when-node-is-r/50999493#50999493) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52768681/what-is-the-difference-between-orientation-and-rotation-in-scnnode/52779622#52779622).

And in case you need to lock any axis for rotation, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430524/lock-camera-rotation-around) post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it does not create the desired result. I have made a screen recording of what it does here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zVCl64M494

Comment: as you can see it is nearly working but not quite like this :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1SA3AZumeU&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Check a position of a pivot point of your plate model! And contrain rotation to only Y axis.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: To control pivot's position read this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61984938/scnnode-is-not-appearing-in-correct-position/62246640#62246640

Comment: legend! Thank you so much!